# Can't get discord webhook to send with json

Tags: python, json, discord

I've been trying to make a discord webhook, and for some reason I can't get it to send to save my life. I have all the embeds in a json file, and am trying to run it with python. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

json file:

```
{
    "embeds": [
      {
        "title": "Title",
        "color": 11393254,
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Name1",
            "value": "value1"
          },
          {
            "name": "Name2",
            "value": "value2",
            "inline": true
          },
      ],
        "footer": {
          "text": "Footer",
          "icon_url": "random image url"
        },
        "timestamp": "now",
        "thumbnail": {
          "url": "random image url"
        }
      }
    ],
    "username": "Username"
  }
```

python code:

```
import requests, json

with open('webhook.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

url = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxxxx'
headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}

requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: I know @Arthur Borshenko asked this, but what status code are you getting back?

Comment: that's the thing - after i run it, i don't get any errors. it runs smoothly but just nothings sends to my discord. the webhook link is valid

Answer (score -1):

What's the status code you get back from the POST? That could be a clue where it's going awry.

Comment: Please put questions for the op commenting under the main question.

Comment: @SpectralWave, he doesn't have enough rep to do that yet I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @SpectralWave - wish I could, I don't have enough rep. Suppose I shouldn't try to answer before I get the required amount.

Comment: that's the thing - after i run it, i don't get any errors. it runs smoothly but just nothings sends to my discord. the webhook link is valid

Comment: @Brian, the thing is that requests wouldn't necessarily error out. You need to check the HTTP response. Try setting the response to a variable and printing it out `r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)` `print(r)`

Comment: @ArthurBorshenko ooh i see, just ran it and i'm getting back <Response [400]>. maybe that's a clue?

Comment: looks like you're sending a bad requests. try `print(r.reason)`

Comment: @ArthurBorshenko yep thats exactly what it says. still can't figure out where it's going wrong :/